# Needs to code when rotate the device?

Tags: android

I am getting error when I rotate the device (it was HTC with Verizon):

```
The application My App (process com.mycompany.android) has
stopped unexpectadly. Please try again.
```

So, I think I need to code for this issue. In order words, when rotate the device from landscape to portable or from portable to landscape, application needs to catch this event.

Is it right ?

How to make it ? What is wrong here ?

Edit: Is it possible to test on the emulator ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To test in an emulator the shortcut to switch the view is KEYPAD_9, Ctrl-F12 (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Android activities are shut down and restarted on a configuration change. The easiest way to get around this is to add [android:configChanges](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) the the application manifest. This will tell Android that you will handle the listed config changes yourself. For example

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

In your manifest means the activity will not restart on an orientation change or if the user has slid out a keyboard.

Comment: Great, I was searching this. I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, Android (by default) destroys and re-creates your Activity when you change orientations. Does that sound like it might cause a problem in your application? There's an [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html) on the Android Developer's blog, and there is a [post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/75dc91441a151039) on the Android Developer's mailing list that describes a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for response. 
It sounds like difficult to solve for my issue. Because when current activity starts, this activity connects to ftp server. Then it generates data to use in a thread. 
So, every in rotation do I need to connect to, to process .... ?

What way is the best ?

Please advice guys.

Comment: You can use an `AsyncTask` to do stuff in the background from your `Activity`, or create a `Service` which holds open your connection and bind to it from your `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

In the case when it is known that a new instance will immediately be created for the new configuration.

The Activity function [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) allows you to store extensive state from the old to new activity instance, from loaded bitmaps, to network connections, to evenly actively running threads.

After implementing this method the result can be used in the onCreate() or onStart() with the function [getLastNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance%28%29).

Comment: Good to hear. Btw, the stackoverflow system works best when pressing the uparrow above the number left of useful answers. :)